# Cloned, file upload and preview issue with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a clone creation command. The id parameter created as clone is as follows (example: id = "myid_1"), increments it by one and makes id = "myid_2". So far there is no problem. That way, each object has a unique ID value, but a simple file upload and preview function within these clones causes my function to malfunction.

I created a simple example on jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/magecode/mbk9ps2x/12/

The problem I understand here is that the id value of the file upload in the onhange event must increase in parallel with the image preview id. For this, I resorted to the attr function and tried to increase the id in parallel, but it never changed.

The code I want to do in the example. The value i is always incrementing but is not added to the cloned object.

```html
<div class="clonable-block" data-toggle="cloner">
<a href="#" id="addrow" class="btn btn-info btn-block clonable-button-add" style="border-radius: 0px; font-size: 13px;">
  <i class="fa fa-file pr-2"></i>Add Row</a>
  <div class="clonable">
    <br/>
  <br/>
      <img id="upload_1" alt="your image" width="100" height="100" class="clonable-increment-id" />
      <input type="file" id="preview_1"
      onchange="document.getElementById('upload_1').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
        <br/>
  <br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
       var i = 1;
    $("#addrow").click(function () {
        i++;

        $("#upload_" + i+"").attr("onchange", "document.getElementById('preview_'+ i + '').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])");

    });
```

Comment: Hi Mustafa!, i saw your fiddle. The problem is that when you change an image, the image change on the first row, not on the row you wanted to be change. Maybe the problem is not that, but just to clarify.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your valuable comment. Actually I understand the problem, but I am having problems on how to solve it. My preview ID is increasing, and with it the ID value in "onchange" should also increase, but I couldn't find a way to increase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated this with vanilla.js, you can then transform it to Jquery.
The thing is that it could be much easier. I recommend you vanilla.js, it has a better overall performance, but i understand the simplicity of Jquery.
Here it goes:

```js
const CloneSource = document.querySelector(".clonable-source");
const buttonRow = document.getElementById("add_row");
const clonesContainer = document.getElementById("clones");
let globalCounter = 1; // Create a globalCounter for the Form IDs

window.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  let target = e.target
  // This try catch is just for strictly saying that we 
  // want to target the .clonable class
  try {
    let form = target.closest(".clonable")
    let fd = new FormData(form)
    let img = fd.get("img");
    let preview = form.children[0]
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(img)
    preview.setAttribute("src", url);
  } catch {
    console.log("No Form")
  }

})

buttonRow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // Creates Form, img, and input elements
  let formSource = document.getElementById("source")
  let Form = document.createElement("form")
  let Img = document.createElement("img")
  let Input = document.createElement("input")
  Form.className = `clonable clonable-clone`
  Form.setAttribute("id", `clonable-${globalCounter}`) // This add the ID to the Form
  
  globalCounter++; // Sum 1 to the globalCounter;      

  Img.setAttribute("src", formSource.children[0].getAttribute("src"))

  Input.setAttribute("type", "file")
  Input.setAttribute("name", "img")

  Form.appendChild(Img)
  Form.appendChild(Input)
  // Then append the form to the clones container
  clonesContainer.appendChild(Form);
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
<div id="clones">
  <form class="clonable clonable-source" id="source">
    <img src="#">
    <input type="file" name="img">
    <p>Select an Image</p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey this is great and works just fine. However, that didn't work when I tried to get it working properly with my current cloning method. I have items such as "select", "login". I have a form where I registered all of them with different IDs. therefore, the IDs must be different.
Also thank you for the advice, I'm new to this and I will definitely follow your advice after this job.

Comment: Perfect, so you have to add dynamic IDs. You can add, inside the **buttonRow** event listener, the IDs for the **Form** variable we created and create a counter outside the function that sum 1 everytime the **buttonRow** it's clicked. I will edit the answer with that ID in mind.